# Pandas counting the null values and plotting in seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I need to plot the count plot for a data set which has blank values.

I tried using

`sns.countplot(x='ViolLevel',data=df1)`

But this produces a plot:

[image]

which does not show the count of the null values (29740) in the data. (I find the number of null values using `df1['ViolLevel'].isnull().sum()`)

How can I include the `nan` values in my count plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the null values in your dataset with a string and run the plot again:

```
df1.ViolLevel.fillna('Null', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default searborn will not include `nan` data in its plots. If you want only want to visualize how much data is missing you can probably substitute the value in the DataFrame that you're trying to visualize temporarily:

```
sns.countplot(data=df1.ViolLevel.fillna('Missing'))
```

It will look like this[image]